# Connecting PS4 through SonicWall TZ100 firewall | Sony Error NW 31162-3

Tags: networking, firewall, port-forwarding, sniffing

I am attempting to Connect my PlayStation 4 through my SonicWall TZ100.  I have below Ports Forwarded.  I'm not great with Packet capturing, but as far as I can tell nothing is getting bounced that is going to PS4's IP Address.  I even paid $170 for called Sonic Wall's support and they didn't help. (Yet)

- Sony said if it works connected directly to internet it's not their problem.
- Tried setting up DMZ.
- Allowed a multicast packet I found through.
- Disabled security services on both LAN/WAN (Content Filtering).
- Disabled Virus Protection LAN/WAN
- Connecting through cable instead of Wireless (better connection anywho)

How can I filter what is being dropped (properly) and what shouldn't get dropped to the WAN Primary IP Address?  (Trying to figure out).

I use a SonicWall because I connect to work directly through VPN which is rather nice, and it's very secure (Even when I don't want it).  Any idea's or knowledge of how to get it working please let me know.

BTW Yes I know something is obviously bouncing and yes It connects to the internet, just get a NAT Type Failure

```
TCP     80      80
TCP    443     443
TCP    465     465
TCP    983     983
TCP   1935    1935
TCP   3478    3480
UDP   3478    3479
TCP   5223    5223
TCP  10070   10080
UDP  10070   10070
UDP   3658    3658
```

Comment: Well magically after much stress and trouble; PlayStation 4 after an update started to at least test as though it works properly.  The above settings worked.  I still have issues with one game, but the speed test works at least.

Answer (score 3):

Enable consistent NAT on your SonicWall (to be found under VOIP settings).  I would have voted this up above, but am a new user.

The consistent NAT setting changes the router into using same translated pairs (security issue as hackers look for predictability).  Sony PS is built on older security principals and is dependent on VOIP for communication (voice chat etc), plus the same for the all the required ports.  I don't understand why Sony would continue to use less secure features.  Even my super cheap MagicJack supports the more secure NAT.

It would be nice if this could be controlled under the NAT policies, but apparently it is an all or nothing setting on SonicWall OS version 5.8.1.x and later on a TZ205.

You can read more about the NAT settings: http://help.mysonicwall.com/sw/eng/1531/ui2/13000/Firewall/VoIP.htm

Comment: For anyone else that finds this answer after a google search: For a PS3 you may also need to disable SSL Control on the SonicWall (under Firewall Settings -> SSL Control on mine) or at least set it to log instead of block. I found the PS3 would not connect to PSN until I disabled detection of expired and self-signed certificates as well as certificates from an untrusted CA (which pretty much makes the service useless on the firewall).

Comment: With consistent NAT disabled, a PS3 will get a Type 3 NAT, which will interfere with games. With consistent NAT enabled, it will get a Type 2 NAT, which is what is desired, and you won't need to forward any ports.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a double NAT because both your firewall and your router/modem are performing the same service. You need to bridge either your router/modem or your TZ.

Comment: Cable modem only gives me one IP Address and is not configurable.  That IP Address is public.  I have to use a DDNS server because it's not static; but besides that I don't know what you are talking about.

Comment: Actually I get what you are saying, but like I said my public IP Address is assigned to my SonicWall.

Answer (score 0):

Make a Policy rule for ANY/LAN --> ANY/Public (WAN)
And try to find a way to enable UPnP if available.  Usually, if the connection is enable by Client, the Firewall will accept response.  In other way, your device will be able to go anywhere and get answer but it will stay hidden from Public side.  UPnP will help PS4/PS3 but it's not enabled on my PS3 and it work find.
If you want to isolate your PS4 from other device (to have different security for other device or computer), you can specify a reserved Private IP instead using "LAN" or create a new Network by user one of the other port on the SonicWALL TZ.

I hope this can help...

Comment: UPnP is not avalible for SonicWall

Answer (score 0):

I have the SonicWall NSA 240. Ip assign to PS4 but not able to connect to PSNetwork. The following works for me: "For anyone else that finds this answer after a google search: For a PS3 you may also need to disable SSL Control on the SonicWall (under Firewall Settings -> SSL Control on mine) or at least set it to log instead of block. I found the PS3 would not connect to PSN until I disabled detection of expired and self-signed certificates as well as certificates from an untrusted CA (which pretty much makes the service useless on the firewall). – user1663987 Mar 20 '15 at 4:58"

Answer (score 0):

I set my Sonicwall TZ400 to:

Enable consistent NAT (its unchecked by default)

and now im getting NAT Type 2 instead of NAT Type 3

Comment: This looks like commentary on Spamhater007's answer, or a new question, rather than a solution to the original question.

Comment: Unfortunately same issue has popped up again... I have a TZ100 not TZ400... exactly where is Consistent NAT?  Is it on PS4? 

More details even if it is on PS4 if on TZ400 where exactly is this setting?  I can look for it on mine (OS's look similar)

Answer (score 0):

Well consistent NAT no longer creates TYPE 2 nat conditions...

I also have a custom zone with everything open from WAN > PS4 (custom zone) with the PS4 directly connected to the TZ105 and still the NAT TYPE errors.

It is a double NAT of sorts because I'm on spUverse and they require their own POS modem which has a router and the only real option is setting up "Bridge mode" on it - but my particular router doesn't have a true bridge mode as they used to... it's more of a DMZ passthrough.

Answer (score 0):

SonicWall SE here.  I am not certain what SonicOS version we added this without looking but now you can mitigate via a NAT policy setting.  See SonicWall KB "Restricted PlayStation functionalities due to NATv3" found at https://www.sonicwall.com/en-us/support/knowledge-base/171204070735334 or just Google for the KB name.

Answer (score -1):

Enable consistent NAT on your SonicWall (to be found under VOIP settings).

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.